# How to install erlang with odbc via brew for mac os x?

Tags: macos, erlang, homebrew

I try to install erlang with odbc via `brew`. I removed old version erlang `brew uninstall --force erlang` and installed odbc `brew install unixodbc` then ran command `brew install --odbc erlang`. But odbc is not running. What is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

HomeBrew Erlang build doesn't support odbc. You should use [kerl](https://github.com/kerl/kerl) for this. Build erlang with `KERL_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS="--disable-hipe --enable-smp-support --enable-threads --enable-kernel-poll --with-odbc --enable-darwin-64bit` option.